# How to unit test a method that uses DateTime.Now in C#?

Tags: c#, datetime, testing

Assume we have a class called Values, and the constructor must have this signature:

```
public Values(DateTime dateTimeTo = default){
   //some code
   if (default == dateTimeTo)
     DateTimeTo = DateTime.Now;
   else
     DateTimeTo = dateTimeTo;
}
```

I want to write a test for this method, specifically i want to test if when Values() is invoked, the DateTimeTo property is assigned correctly.

Obvioulsy writing a test like this will not work:

```
       [Test]
        public void Values_DefaultParameters_CreateValuesIstance()
        {
            DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
            
            Values v = new Values();

            Assert.That(v.DateTimeTo, now);
        }
```

Since the two DateTime.Now assignments happen in different time.

I have also tried to use create a new interface:

```
    public interface IDateTimeProvider {
     
        DateTime getCurrentDateTime();
    }
```

And to create 2 classes, the first returns the current DateTime:

```
 public class DateTimeProvider : IDateTimeProvider{

        public DateTime getCurrentDateTime()
        {
            return DateTime.Now;
        }
    }
```

And a fake that return a settable DateTime:

```
public class FakeDateTimeProvider : IDateTimeProvider
        {
            public DateTime Date { get; set; }
            public DateTime getCurrentDateTime()
            {
                return Date;
            }
        }
```

But when i change the constructor

```
public Values(IDateTimeProvider? dateTimeTo = default){
//some code
   if (default == dateTimeTo)
     DateTimeTo = dateTimeTo.getCurrentDateTime(); //Error
   else
     DateTimeTo = dateTimeTo;
}
```

i get an error since the default value of a IDateTimeProvider type is null.

Comment: More options can be found at https://start.duckduckgo.com/?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+c%23+unit+test+datetime.now&ia=web

Comment: I have already tried to use interfaces so that I can inject fake objects. However, if for example i change the parameter from DateTime to IDateTimeProvider, then I encounter a problem as the default value of IDateTimeProvider would be null.

Comment: Please [edit] your post with your attempt at using interfaces. See more advice at [mre].

Comment: Injected dependencies in constructors should not be optional, meaning that `IDateTimeProvider` should never be null. That only leads to complexity in the consumer as you can see in your `Values` constructor. Besides that, you should not use an injected dependency in the constructor; its usage should be delayed until after the constructor has ran.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But when I change the constructor

You are almost there. The only thing should be corrected is that after the redesign `Values` should have 2 parameters rather than one. Something along these lines:

```cs
class Values
{
    public Values(IDateTimeProvider dateTimeProvider, DateTime dateTimeTo = default)
    {
        DateTimeTo = default == dateTimeTo 
            ? dateTimeProvider.GetCurrentDateTime()
            : dateTimeTo;
    }

    public DateTime DateTimeTo { get; set; }
}
```

If you really want to make this dependency optional then you can check if it is null and act appropriately - for example using [null conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-):

```cs
class Values
{
    public Values(DateTime dateTimeTo = default, IDateTimeProvider? dateTimeProvider = null)
    {
        DateTimeTo = default == dateTimeTo 
            ? dateTimeProvider?.GetCurrentDateTime() ?? DateTime.Now
            : dateTimeTo;
    }

    public DateTime DateTimeTo { get; set; }
}
```

Read More:

- There is request for something similar to be introduced in framework and possibly we will see it with .NET 8 - see this [github issue](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/36617).
- [Reference types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/reference-types) - interface are passed by reference, so the default value is `null`